# Reactor Flux incompatible types when compose

Tags: java, flux, reactor

I don't understand what's wrong, but when I chain the Flux, I get an error.

I have a factory class to MyObj

```
@Service
public class MyObjFactory {

   public MyObj create(JSONObject myObj) {
       return null;
   }
}
```

While that code doesn't raise an error

```
@Autowired
private MyObjFactory myObjFactory;

private Flux<MyObj> parseMyObj() throws IOException, ParseException {
   JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("c:\\myobj.json"));
   Flux<Object> f1 = Flux.fromIterable(jsonArray);
   Flux<JSONObject> f2 = f1.cast(JSONObject.class);
   Flux<Vlb> f3 = f2.map(myObjFactory::create);
   return f3;
}
```

that code raise:
java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
        incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to org.json.simple.JSONObject

```
@Autowired
private MyObjFactory myObjFactory;

private Flux<MyObj> parseMyObj() throws IOException, ParseException {
   JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("c:\\myobj.json"));
   return Flux.fromIterable(jsonArray)
          .cast(JSONObject.class)
          .map(myObjFactory::create);
}
```